# Error: Cannot find module 'load-grunt-tasks'

Tags: node.js

unable to run "grunt serve"

Getting below attached error, please do the needful

[image]

```
C:\wamp\www\ui\app>npm install
npm ERR! install Couldn't read dependencies
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! node v4.3.1
npm ERR! npm  v2.14.12
npm ERR! path C:\wamp\www\ui\app\package.json
npm ERR! code ENOPACKAGEJSON
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! syscall open

npm ERR! package.json ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\wamp\www\ui\app\package.json'
npm ERR! package.json This is most likely not a problem with npm itself.
npm ERR! package.json npm can't find a package.json file in your current directory.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\wamp\www\ui\app\npm-debug.log

C:\wamp\www\ui\app>grunt serve
Loading "Gruntfile.js" tasks...ERROR
>> Error: Cannot find module 'load-grunt-tasks'
Warning: Task "serve" not found. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

Answer (score 2):

Run `npm install` before `grunt serve`.

If that doesn't help, then you need to `npm install --save-dev load-grunt-tasks`

Comment: I have attached my issue notes when i ran npm install

Answer (score 1):

You can try this :

```
npm install load-grunt-tasks
```

generally when you have :

```
Error Cannot find module 'module_name'
```

then `npm install module_name` for installing your module!